# How to expand object properties and local variables from string in PHP

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to get a network device template configuration from mongo and use it to configure the device. So I have a classDevice with properties relating to device and CRUD methods to manipulate the devices. My problem here is that I'm not getting how to expand the class properties. I've tryed putting the properties in `$vars` with `get_object_vars` but the result is the same, empty variable.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

class Device {

    public $ip;
    public $mode;

    public function __construct($data = false)
    {
        $this->ip = $data['ip'];
        $this->mode = $data['mode'];
    }

    public function configure(){
        if ($this->mode == 'bridge'){
            $localvar = 'test';
        }
        $template = array('0' => 'set ip $this->ip', '1' => 'set mode $this->mode', '2' => 'set calculated attr $localvar');
        $cfgexpanded = array();
        foreach ($template as $config) {
            preg_match_all('/\$([a-zA-Z0-9\-\>]+)/', $config, $variables, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
            foreach($variables[1] as $variable){
                $config = str_replace('$'.$variable, $$variable, $config);
            }
            array_push($cfgexpanded, $config);
        }
        var_dump($cfgexpanded);
    }
}

$data['ip'] = '1.2.3.4';
$data['mode'] = 'bridge';

$test = new Device($data);
$test->configure();
?>
```

This produces:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this->ip in /home/pedro/test.php on line 23
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this->mode in /home/pedro/test.php on line 23
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "set ip "
  [1]=>
  string(9) "set mode "
  [2]=>
  string(24) "set calculated attr test"
}
```

And this is the real code, where $cfg is a Mongo returned Object that contains the template to apply where I have local variables and object properties:

```
            foreach ($cfg['cfg'] as $config) {
$$replace, $config));               
                preg_match_all('/\$([a-zA-Z0-9\-\>]+)/', $config, $variables, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
                foreach($variables[1] as $variable){
                    $config = str_replace('$'.$variable, $$variable, $config);
                }
                array_push($cfgexpanded, $config);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your searching for `$"this->ip"` as a string variable instead of object `$this->ip` if that makes sense. Try this:

```
foreach($variables[1] as $variable){
  $var = strpos($variable, '->') !== false ? $this->{end(explode('->', $variable))} : $$variable;
  $config = str_replace('$'.$variable, $var, $config);
}
```

Comment: But there are local variables too, I do some calculations inside the method so I need them.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Not tested but you should get the idea I hope.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only does inline variable expansion in double quotes. Change

```
    $template = array('0' => 'set ip $this->ip', '1' => 'set mode $this->mode', '2' => 'set calculated attr $localvar');
```

To

```
    $template = array('0' => "set ip {$this->ip}", '1' => "set mode {$this->mode}", '2' => "set calculated attr {$localvar}");
```

The curly braces aren't strictly necessary, but I find them to make the code more readable.

Comment: Yes, in this example the double quotes do the trick. But in reality this array comes from a query in mongo database and already comes with double quotes (as var_dump shows me) so I think this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the fact that you are mistaking a human readable form of a variable to also be machine readable. Your regex filters out the variable string which you read as 1 variable, but to the machine is a variable on a variable, e.g. variable `ip` on the `this` variable. The thing is, when you extract the variable by regex, you get basically 1 string, without the object oriented intelligence.

But maybe you don't even need the regex? If you already know the variables in the template, why not do it like this;

```php
<?php

class Device {

    public $ip;
    public $mode;

    public function __construct($data = false)
    {
        $this->ip = $data['ip'];
        $this->mode = $data['mode'];
    }

    public function configure(){
        if ($this->mode == 'bridge'){
            $localvar = 'test';
        }
        $template = array('0' => 'set ip ' . $this->ip, '1' => 'set mode ' . $this->mode, '2' => 'set calculated attr ' . $localvar);
        var_dump($template);
        return $template;
    }
}

$data['ip'] = '1.2.3.4';
$data['mode'] = 'bridge';

$test = new Device($data);
$test->configure();
?>
```

Or does the template come from the database? In that case it might be better to not use the `$this->` string, but only keep `$ip`, than trying of the `ip` and use `property_exists` on the class to check if the property is present. If so, replace the string in the new array.

Comment: Yes, the template comes from database, this code is just an example but judging by the answers maybe not the best one. Inside the method there are some calculations, this is why I need to parse local variables + object properties. I've tried sort of what you sayed I think, using get_object_vars to pass properties to array but the results are the same.